# Не выходит реализовать запуск сервиса после того как отсчет закончен

Tags: java, android

у меня возникла проблема... не выходит реализовать сервис(а именно звук alarm) после того как отсчет достигнет конца то-есть 00:00.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText time;
    private TextView introduction;
    private long Mtime;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private Button cleartimer, accepttimer, start, reset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        time = findViewById(R.id.et_set_time_off_device);
        accepttimer = findViewById(R.id.b_first_button);
        introduction = findViewById(R.id.tv_introduction);
        cleartimer = findViewById(R.id.v_second_button);




        start = accepttimer;
        reset = cleartimer;

        start.setOnClickListener(this);
        reset.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    private void starttimer(){
        Mtime = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());
       mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(Mtime * 60000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                time.setText("" + String.format(" %02d minutes,  %02d seconds ",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)-
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                time.setText("Конец");

            }
        }.start();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        if(view == start) {
            starttimer();
            startService(new Intent(this, CustomService.class));
       
        }


        if(view == reset) {
            mCountDownTimer.cancel();
            time.setText("");
            stopService(new Intent(this, CustomService.class));

            }
    }
}
```

Код сервиса

```
import android.app.Service;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;


public class CustomService extends Service {
    private MediaPlayer player;
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, (Settings.System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI));
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        player.stop();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: у вас звук 1 раз проигрывается или в цикле некоторое время?

Answer (score 0):

Когда таймер закончится, то сработает метод onFinish() в MainActivity и по логике - там должен запускаться MediaPlayer со звуком оповещения. А у вас там только вывод в тексте "Конец".

```
public void onFinish() {
                time.setText("Конец");  }
```

Нет связи конца таймера с сервисом. Если я все правильно понял.

Вообще обычно CountDownTimer запускают в сервисе, а не в Активити, чтобы не зависит от его lifecycle.

Comment: а что это за метод onFinish ? покажите в документации хочу пополнить свои знания